# Tor upgraded to 0.3.0.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but Atlas still says "Outdated Tor version"

Tags: ubuntu, tor-install

When Atlas told me that my Tor node was running an "Outdated Tor version" I upgraded Tor on my node (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Trusty) system.

Atlas now tells me that my platform is "Tor 0.3.0.10 on Linux" (as I expected) but it is still saying 5 hours later that it is an "Outdated Tor version".

Have I missed something?

UPDATE: I note a message from Roger Dingledine on the tor-relays mailing list that suggests that this might be an issue with only one (on 5 August) of the three dir auth servers recommending 0.3.0.10. However it is now 22 August and they should all be updated.

Comment: My relay is running 0.3.0.10 and reports that it is a recommended version. Where are you seeing this message?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem has cleared but it took more than 24 hours. The message was on the page returned by Atlas. Under 'Platform' it said (correctly) 'Tor 0.3.0.10 on Linux'. Under 'Properties', however, it said (incorrectly) 'Outdated Tor version' prefixed by a red symbol. Those have now been replaced by the text 'none' which is normal.

Comment: Atlas is often outdated, it can lag behind by quite some time from the latest consensus. It gets its information from Onionoo which is really just an API into the consensus, but often it's not running off the latest consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Very frustrating. I updated to Tor 0.3.0.8 on Linux....and Atlas classifies this relay as "Outdated Tor version".

Surely this can be fixed?